# zero degree fahrenheit vs zero degrees fahrenheit

Tags: grammatical-number

> The frozen foods are kept **at zero *degree* fahrenheit**.
>
> The frozen foods are kept **at zero *degrees* fahrenheit**.

Which one is correct?  Which i use degree or degrees
as adjective ?

Answer (score 2):

"Zero" calls for the plural of any noun:

> Zero gallons of gas.
>
> Zero degrees Celsius.
>
> Zero miles to go.
>
> Zero people agree with me.

"One" calls for the singular:

> One gallon of gas.
>
> One degree Celsius.
>
> One mile to go.
>
> One person agrees with me.

Answer (score 1):

When referring to the temperature, you use *zero degrees Fahrenheit*.

> The temperature in the freezer is **zero degrees Fahrenheit**.

However, if you use the phrase as a modifier, then you use *zero degree Fahrenheit*:

> To check the quality of our parts, we use a **zero degree Fahrenheit** test chamber.